# search not working properly with react-infinity-menu

Tags: reactjs

I am using [react-infinity-menu](https://github.com/socialtables/react-infinity-menu) in my project. When I search for a particular string it's giving correct results but when I erase that string from search filed then it's not showing the results correctly. it's still showing old search results.
Any idea?

**Search filed code**

```
<bs.Input type='text' id='id1' className='form-control' placeholder='Search...' value={this.props.searchInput}
  onChange={this.props.setSearchInput} />;
```

**Infinity menu code:**

```
  <InfinityMenu
          headerContent={Header}
          headerProps={{ value: 'dummy' }}
          emptyTreeComponent={EmptyComponent}
          tree={this.state.categories}
          onLeafMouseClick={this.onLeafMouseClick}
          onNodeMouseClick={this.onNodeMouseClick} />
```

Comment: can you add the code for `this.props.setSearchInput` please?

Comment: Sorry I didn't write any code for that.

Comment: do you see any console errors when you type or delete text from the imput

Comment: No, I didn't  see any errors on the console.

Comment: Any ideas What I am missing?

Comment: @bennygenel can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry. I've never worked with infinity menu so I don't know how to help.